# Get rid of Android navigation drawer translucency

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app, I'm using the navigation drawer from the support library. It is translucent by default, and setting it or its childrens' background color just adds a translucent version of this color. 
This is the drawer and its two children:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer_p"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="@color/grey"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 13):

You want to `setScrimColor` with zero alpha.

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.parseColor("#00FFFFFF"));
```

where `R.id.drawer_layout` is the id of my `DrawerLayout`

Answer (score 5):

I dont really understand your question, but if you are trying to make the navigation drawer transparent then use the following code:

```
android:background="#60FFFFFF"
```

Where the '60' is about 38% transparency (60 in hex is 96 in decimal, so 96/255 %).

But if your navigation drawer is already transparent I have used the code:

```
android:background="#FFFFFF"
```

It works fine and it is not transparent.

Both colours are the HTML colour code for white, a simple google search will find you the code for other colours.

Comment: I shouldn't have said transparent in the title, sorry. The android:background=@color/grey line in the listview goes to a hex code and does control the background color. It's not transparent, just translucent; i.e. I can see buttons that are beneath the listview. Changing the color doesn't help.

Comment: I know this is picky, but 60 is not the transparency %. It is hexadecimal for 96 and goes from 0-255, so is ~38% translucency.